# My bot will send messages when other bots send messages

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I have my discord bot log messages as they get sent by users in my server, but whenever other bots send messages I want the bot to not log there messages. How do I do this

Log code:

```
 @client.event
    async def on_message(ctx):
        if ctx.author != client.user:
            log_msg = client.get_channel(1003447126501625856)
            await log_msg.send(f"""**Message sent by: {ctx.author.mention} in {ctx.channel.mention}.
            Message:** "{ctx.content}" """)
            print(f"""**Message sent by: {ctx.author} in {ctx.channel}.
            Message:** "{ctx.content}" """)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the incoming [author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=author#discord.Message.author) of the [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=author#message) is a [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=author#discord.User.bot). If so, return None.

```py
async def on_message(ctx):
    # return if the message is from a bot
    if ctx.author.bot: return  # noqa: E701
```

Sources:

- discord.py 2.0 -> [Github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)
- discord.py 2.0 -> [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: Your comment about discord.py is very out of date, development has resumed and Version 2.0 has been released over a month ago.

Comment: @moinierer3000, oh wow! That is actually pretty nifty. Ill update my answer! Thanks for pointing this out.